# embedding for categorical variable and pass to keras network

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have tabular data with two columns , one is input feature and anther one is target variable.
I have converted the input feature to embeddings and pass on to Keras model layer, getting error while executing fit method.
here is the code which i have used for this.
df is the input dataframe and contains two columns.

```
X = df.drop(columns = ['data_type']).copy()
y = df['data_type']

X_train, X_rem, y_train, y_rem = train_test_split(X,y, train_size=0.8)
X_valid, X_test, y_valid, y_test = train_test_split(X_rem,y_rem, test_size=0.5)

Y_train=pd.DataFrame({'data_type':y_train})
Y_valid=pd.DataFrame({'data_type':y_valid})
Y_test=pd.DataFrame({'data_type':y_test})

enc = OrdinalEncoder()
X_train[["data"]] = enc.fit_transform(X_train[["data"]])
X_valid[["data"]] = enc.fit_transform(X_valid[["data"]])
X_test[["data"]] = enc.fit_transform(X_test[["data"]])

X_train_actual = []
X_train_actual.append(np.array(X_train["data"]).reshape(-1,1))
X_valid_actual = []
X_valid_actual.append(np.array(X_valid["data"]).reshape(-1,1))

Y_train["data_type"] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(Y_train["data_type"])
Y_valid["data_type"] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(Y_valid["data_type"])
Y_test["data_type"] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(Y_test["data_type"])

Y_train_actual= to_categorical(Y_train.to_numpy())
Y_valid_actual= to_categorical(Y_valid.to_numpy())

embedding_size = 50
categories  = 7

inputs = Input(shape=(1,))
embedding_layer = Embedding(categories, 
                            embedding_size, 
                            embeddings_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01), 
                            input_length=1)(inputs)
cat_input_layers = Reshape(target_shape=(embedding_size,))(embedding_layer)
```

building the layers is as follows.

```
dense_1 = Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01))(cat_input_layers)

final_out = Dense(7, activation='softmax')(dense_1)   

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=final_out)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.00001)

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                                     save_weights_only=True,
                                                     verbose=1)
early_stop = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5)

history = model.fit(X_train_actual,
                        Y_train_actual,
                        batch_size=100,
                        epochs=500,
                        validation_data =(X_valid_actual, Y_valid_actual),
                        callbacks=[checkpoint, early_stop],
                        verbose=1)



getting the error when i am executing the fit call.
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [336], line 1
----> 1 history = model.fit(X_train_actual,
      2                     Y_train_actual,
      3                     batch_size=100,
      4                     epochs=500,
      5                     validation_data =(X_valid_actual, Y_valid_actual),
      6                     callbacks=[checkpoint, early_stop],
      7                     verbose=1)

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\keras-tf-tcb\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

any idea, what exactly the issue,
```

Comment: Have you removed `nan` values from your input column?

Comment: there are no NaN's, here is the complete log.